What is every charm combo in Hollow Knight?
In Hollow Knight, some charms have secret interactions with each other when they're both equipped. For example, pairing Grubsong with Weaversong gives you soul every time one of your Weaverlings strikes an enemy.
What is every charm combo in the game?

The list in question can be found on the following wiki page. Here are the details:



First charm
Second charm
Synergy effect




Dashmaster
Sharp Shadow
Increases the damage dealt by the shadow to 1.5 x Nail damage. Does not affect charge or cooldown time.


Dashmaster
Sprintmaster
Further increases the movement speed bonus to 39%.


Fury of the Fallen
Glowing Womb
Increases any spawned hatchlings' contact damage by 5 when on 1 Mask.


Fury of the Fallen
Grubberfly's Elegy
Fires red projectiles at one Mask, dealing ~67.5% Nail damage per projectile.


Mark of Pride
Grubberfly's Elegy
Increases the size of the projectiles from Grubberfly's Elegy by 35%.


Defender's Crest
Flukenest
Replaces the horde of flukes with one massive, volatile fluke that does 3 impact damage and explodes into a dung cloud that does 1 damage per tick for 23 ticks.


Defender's Crest
Glowing Womb
Lowers Hatchling contact damage by 5, adding it back in the form of a 1-second dung cloud that does on average 4-5 damage.


Defender's Crest
Spore Shroom
Increases the damage of the spore cloud to 2 damage per tick and makes the cloud last 4.1 seconds. However, tick frequency is decreased, allowing for only 20 ticks (40 total damage). Changes the visuals of the cloud.


Quick Focus
Shape of Unn
Doubles the movement speed of the Shape of Unn form (6.0 -> 12.0).


Deep Focus
Spore Shroom
Increases the spore cloud radius by 35%.


Joni's Blessing
Hiveblood
Hiveblood regenerates Lifeblood Masks granted directly by Joni's Blessing, though it takes twice as long (20 seconds). Changes the visuals of the Knight's Masks.


Grubsong
Grubberfly's Elegy
The amount of SOUL received from taking damage is increased by 10 (to 25).


Grubsong
Weaversong
The Weaverlings collect 3 SOUL upon striking an enemy.


Dream Wielder
Dreamshield
The shield is 15% larger.


Weaversong
Sprintmaster
Weaverlings move 50% faster.




Good answer so far, but the wiki says, "This page does not list combined effects of two charms that are to be expected, such as Longnail's 15% Nail length increase and Mark of Pride's 25% Nail length increase stacking additively to 40%." Could you include those ones as well, even if they may be obvious?

Equipping any pair of charms gives you the effect of both of those charms. From your point of view, what distinguishes the ones that should be included in this list from the ones that should not?

@murgatroid99 Any charms that have directly stacking effects (such as the aforementioned charms that stack an increase to nail length). (I know this is really late, I forgot about it)
